# Java - How to scale necessary area

Tags: java, swing, zooming, paintcomponent, mousewheel

I use simple grapher and I want to scale red area on mouse wheel. I add `MouseWheelListener`

```
//constructor {
    addMouseWheelListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
            double delta = 0.05f * e.getPreciseWheelRotation();
            scale += delta;
            revalidate();
            repaint();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
    at.scale(scale, scale);
    g2.setTransform(at);
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    // read points in series and add series in dataset...
    // draw white background
    g2.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g2.fillRect(padding + labelPadding, padding, getWidth() - (2 * padding) - labelPadding, getHeight() - 2 * padding - labelPadding);

    // create hatch marks and grid lines for x and y axis...
    // create x and y axes 
    g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, padding + labelPadding, padding);
    g2.drawLine(padding + labelPadding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding, getWidth() - padding, getHeight() - padding - labelPadding);
    //draw graphs...
}

@Override
public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    Dimension size = new Dimension(width, height);
    size.width = Math.round(size.width * scale);
    size.height = Math.round(size.height * scale);
    return size;
}

private static void createAndShowGui() {
    ...
    SimpleGrapher2 mainPanel = new SimpleGrapher2(scores);
    mainPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawGraph");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
        createAndShowGui();
     }
  });
```

}
}

So how can I scale only my red area not all program window?

[image]

[how my code works](http://rghost.ru/8LDMVJfrm/image.png)

Comment: The red area should be a separate JPanel. As for details, I'm afraid that I don't understand your problem well enough to say more. Hopefully others will do better.

Comment: First of all, don't add the MouseWheelListener within the paint method...Second consider providing a runnable example which demonstrates your problem

Comment: @MadProgrammer I added another link with photo how it works

Comment: As Hovercraft suggest, the core graphical area should be it's own component, as you will have issues with the clipping bounds and other fun things if you don't

Comment: @MadProgrammer how can I do it in paintComponent?

Comment: As Mad suggested in his first comment, for better help, consider creating and posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example Program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). We don't want to see your whole program, but rather you should condense your code into the smallest bit that still compiles, has no extra code that's not relevant to your problem, but still demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Can we compile your code? No. Can we run, test, and then modify to correct your code? No. Have you critically read the [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that I've provided above, I kind of doubt. If you still need help, please do all of us a favor and read or re-read the link.

Comment: Yes, you can do it in paintComponent; but for your own sanity, I would make the "graph" portion it's own component . The other method might be to determine the number of points  that would be displayed and simply paint them (like a virtual zoom)